# How to get the record ID of the newly created record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

We are creating the records using the Lightning component like below

```
   var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");

    createRecordEvent.setParams({ 
        "entityApiName": "Contact", 
        "defaultFieldValues": {
            'AccountId':accId,

        }});
    createRecordEvent.fire();
```

Is there any way to get the ID of the created record after the event is fired and the record is saved.

Answer (score 0):

create a callback apex class (@AuraEnabled) which would return the Id when the record is created...

in the callback function check for the Id with the getReturnValue() method from the response..

Hope this helps!!